# Does anyone know how to add meta descriptions to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

This is my first ever post on here. Does anyone know how to add meta descriptions to wordpress?

Many thanks,

Tung

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general wordpress tech support.

Comment: Try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh ok thank you for guiding me in the write direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `Blog description goes here` and add this code into your theme `functions.php`

```
function my_meta_description(){
echo  '<meta name="description" content="Blog description goes here" />';
}
add_action('wp_head','my_meta_description');
```

Comment: Hi Firefog, thanks so much, i will try it now and see if it works. thanks again

Comment: @Tung the help you try to accept the answer and up vote will help you to get good answer.

Comment: Firebug, thank you again for helping this newbie. It's all quite daunting so really appreciate the friendly advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You may setup content of meta description at admin page -> appearance -> customized -> site identity -> tagline (wp 4.4)

to add meta description on page, put this code between head
    `<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it in menu "Appearance" in the "header.php" file. There you can edit ot. Or you can also download one of the wordpress plugins:
Yoast SEO (recommend) or All-in-SEO-pack. It will help you to customize any meta's you need!